# Set the category of an email using custom Outlook Web App Addin

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

I have a scenario where my Outlook Web App Add-in looks for the same email by subject in a database through API. If this email found in the database, I want to mark that email with some categorization so that user can visualize which emails have already been in the Database.

I am using the Office.js to get the subject and pass it to the API as through ajax call. The API written in C# looks into the database and return true or false. 
if it returns true, I want to mark this email with category red from the code automatically.

> Red category means follows.

[image]

Comment: Just to clarify, the subject of your post talks about "update the subject of email", however, the body of your post indicates that you want a way to set a category on an email. Which scenario are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the subject. I want to set the category Red based on the boolean value returned from API.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no way of dynamically setting categories.

We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add a feature request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.